# Folder renaming and alternate homepage for alias domain using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to modify the url for an alias domain. 
We have main-domain.ext and alias-domain.ext.

**Successfully done**
We setup the alias correctly and modified the wordpress site_url and home_url so that alias-domain.ext/page/subpage displays the same information as main-domain.ext/page/subpage.

**Challenge**
Now we would like to go one step further.

We have a page and subpages called main-domain.ext/consultancy and main-domain.ext/consultancy/subpage.
We'd like to set main-domain.ext/consultancy as the homepage of alias-domain.ext, so that main-domain.ext/consultancy/subpage will be displayed as alias-domain.ext/subpage.

Meaning:

alias-domain.ext/ == main-domain.ext/consultancy

alias-domain.ext/subpage == main-domain.ext/consultancy/subpage

alias-domain.ext/any-page == main-domain.ext/consultancy/any-page

Meaning for the alias we'd like to remove the folder name 'consultancy' and we'd like to set the consultancy page as the homepage.

Can we do that by using htaccess? I have been struggling to do this. I don't really understand how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Put this above `#BEGIN WordPress` in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alias-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page_id=ID_OF_SUBPAGE [NC,QSA]
```

replace alias-domain and ID_OF_SUBPAGE and you should be good to go!

[source](https://www.brianshim.com/webtricks/map-domain-name-wordpress-page-post/)

Comment: Your solution only works for ONE subpage, but we'd like it to work for any page. 

e.g. 
alias-domain.ext/ == main-domain.ext/consultancy, alias-domain.ext/subpage == main-domain.ext/consultancy/subpage, alias-domain.ext/any-page == main-domain.ext/consultancy/any-page